# Recalculationg value of XML Attribute

Tags: php, xml, attributes

I have a problem. I get the price list in xml format, the price is encoded in the attribute

<Wholesale_price> xx.xx </Wholesale_price>

I need to globally convert the prices of all products in the price list, e.g. change the value to 110% or 120%. Does anyone have an idea to do this? The file is too long for manual recalculation.

I thought about doing it in a spreadsheet, but the list is very long, and I will have to do it all over again every few days, so I need a less time-consuming solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are just trying to change the value than why not just iterate over the items and add your calculation inside the loop?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm far from being a programmer, so I didn't think of it, but thanks for the hint, at least I know which direction to look for. Thank you.

Comment: You can use XSLT transformation for such tasks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be with the Saxon Gizmo command-line tool:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Gizmo input.xml
/>update //Wholesale_price with . * 1.2
/>save input-updated.xml
/>quit
```

Details at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!gizmo

The expression `. * 1.2` means the new value should be the old value multiplied by 1.2.

Another similar tool is xmlstarlet.